# Programmatically changing the height of a Storyboard view

Tags: ios, uiview, uistoryboard

**Background:**

I have a normal `UIView` in Storyboard (called `statusView`) which has a height of `30`, and four constraints pinned to the leading, trailing, top space to the superview, and bottom space to the view below it.

**Problem:**

My goal is to alter the height of `statusView`, including animating the frame changes when the user performs an action. As such, `statusView` could be as short as `0` or as tall as `100`.

My expectation is that, given `statusView` is constrained to the superview and its nearest neighbor below, it should automatically "push" the views below when I alter its height.

Just to test, in `viewDidAppear`, I call the following:

```
self.statusView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: 100.0)
self.statusView.setNeedsDisplay()
```

**Issue**: However, the height of 30 remains for `statusView`, despite me setting it to `0`.

**Edit:** posted `Storyboard` settings

This is the setting for `statusView`: 
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using autolayout and want to set an explicit height for a view in your hierarchy, you should use autolayout to do it. I am assuming there is a height constraint set up in interface builder.

Create an `IBOutlet` for the constraint and link it up in interface builder.

```
@IBOutlet weak var statusViewHeightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
```

Then, assuming this is just a size constraint with a constant for the height, just change it in your code:

```
statusViewHeightConstraint.constant = 100
```

You can animate this change by wrapping a layout call in an animation block right after modifying your constraint(s). Something like this:

```
UIView.animateKeyframes(withDuration: 0.2, delay: 0.0, options: [.beginFromCurrentState, .calculationModeCubic], animations: {
  self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
}, completion: nil)
```

Comment: This is a great idea - to alter the height constraint. Would I be able to animate the height change via the constraint?

Comment: Fantastic. Thanks so much!